# Taking input file and getting it to display input in a 24 hour clock

Tags: bash, awk

Lets say we have file 1: `1 5 17 10 8 16`
Is there a way to input that file and make it display in 24 hour clock

ex output: `100 hours 500 hours 1700 hours 1000 hours 800 hours 1600 hours`

Comment: What time is 100, 500, and 800 hours?

Comment: `while read -d' ' -r num; do echo "$(date -d"$num" '+%H00 hours')"; done <file1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) gave a partial answer [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436441/80216#comment788536_436441),
but it might not do exactly what you want.

If you have accurately described what you want, it is actually very simple:

```
while read -a nums
do
    for num in "${nums[@]}"
    do
        printf '%d00 hours ' "$num"
    done
done < file1
```

`read -a nums` reads an array of values (i.e., multiple values). 
`"${nums[@]}"` refers to the collection of values
stored in the `nums` array;
`for num in …` loops through them, assigning each one to `num`. 
Then we print each one followed by `00 hours` and a space.

This will print them all on one line, as you have shown in your question. 
To terminate the line, add `echo` or `printf '\n'`
at the end of the above code. 
If you want each one printed on a separate line,
change the `printf` command (in the middle) to

```
        printf '%d00 hours\n' "$num"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1 5 17 10 8 16
1 5 17 10 8 16

$ awk -F" " '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { $i=$i*100" hours"} print }' file

100 hours 500 hours 1700 hours 1000 hours 800 hours 1600 hours
100 hours 500 hours 1700 hours 1000 hours 800 hours 1600 hours
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`:

```
$ printf '%d00 hours ' $(<file)
100 hours 500 hours 1700 hours 1000 hours 800 hours 1600 hours
```

(no newline at the end of output)

With fancier formatting:

```
$ printf '%02d:00 hours\n' $(<file)
01:00 hours
05:00 hours
17:00 hours
10:00 hours
08:00 hours
16:00 hours
```

Comment: Very clever....

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/\100 hours/g' < the_file
```

Comment: Or `sed 's/[0-9]*/&00 hours/g'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Your version chokes if there is whitespace at the beginning or the end of the line, or multiple spaces between numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely agree with @Kusalananda's one liner. Here's a very simple way Quiet lengthy though

```
awk '{print $1*100 " hours",$2*100" hours",$3*100" Hours",$4*100" hours",$5*100" hours" }' < file.txt

100 hours 500 hours 1700 Hours 1000 hours 800 hours
```

Comment: If the challenge were simply to produce the output that the OP showed in the question, you could do `echo 100 hours 500 hours 1700 hours 1000 hours 800 hours 1600 hours` — but that's just an example.  *For **example**,* the sample input file has six numbers in it.  But, in real life, a file might have seven numbers — or even 17!  P.S. Your answer doesn't even handle the example in the question correctly, because it handles only five fields.  (And did you see Bharat's answer?)